# Pro*C: Using host-arrays together with PL/SQL Embedded procedures

Tags: c, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a couple of sentences like this:

```
BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
   struct proc_aux_in
   {
      int field1;
      int field2;
   };

   struct proc_aux_out
   {
       int field1;
       int field2;
   };
END DECLARE SECTION;

void f()
{
   EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
       struct proc_aux_in* proc_in;
       struct proc_aux_out* proc_out;
       unsigned proc_sz; 
   EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

   proc_sz = /* some size */;
   proc_in = /* malloc whatever with proc_sz */;
   proc_out = /* malloc whatever with proc_sz */;

   EXEC SQL FOR :proc_sz
   INSERT INTO some_table (field1, field2) VALUES (:proc_in);

   EXEC SQL FOR :proc_sz
   SELECT O.field1, O.field2 INTO :proc_out
   FROM some_table T
        JOIN some_other_table O on O.key = T.field1 and O.value = T.field2;

   // free's, error control, post-processing, whatever.
}
```

However, if I try to replace the two individual queries it with a embedded PL/SQL block to minimize network roundtrips:

```
   EXEC SQL EXECUTE
   BEGIN
       FOR :proc_sz
       INSERT INTO some_table (field1, field2) VALUES (:proc_in);

       FOR :proc_sz
       SELECT O.field1, O.field2 INTO :proc_out
       FROM some_table T
          JOIN some_other_table O on O.key = T.field2 and O.value = T.field2;
   END;
   END-EXEC;
```

At compilation-time it fails because Pro*C doesn't like the `FOR` clause that is in the first sentence after `BEGIN`, because I guess that's pure Pro*C syntax that does not apply in pure PL/SQL.

What are the alternatives? How to fix it? I hope the solution does not involve opening cursors or doing something more "verbose", because I like the original expressiveness of the code.